Codility lessons of Iterations "use the print statement ended with a comma"
I cannot understand why Python language include a comma at the end of a print statement. I tried to run the code sample in IDE but failed:
Here is the content of the lesson. Please check the image below:
enter image description here
I want to know the lesson is wrong or I am lack of knowledge of Python.

This worked in Python 2.x which is outdated.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You might just need to find a new tutorial, either on Codility on somewhere else. Which tutorial exactly is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

The tutorial is completely outdated. According to the image you provided, the code of the tutorial is using Python version 2.x, which reached its end of life a couple of years ago. Don't use the code, and don't use the tutorial either if it's outdated.

Please check the version of Python you are using and the one which is used in the learnings. The one which is in the picture is Python 2.x and that is completely outdated.
I would suggest you to avoid Python 2.x learnings and go for Python 3.x instead.
I may forward you here https://www.learnpython.org/. Check it out yourself.
